# How to split names into first/middle/last if there are people who typed last/first/middle? Order known

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to split names into first, middle, last, based on an indicated order. I am at a lost on how to do this, and any help would be much appreciated. I am using sql server 2008 for work.

I attached an example dataset and the ideal dataset I would like to create.

```
ID  ORDER                   NAME
1   first, middle, last     Bruce, Batman, Wayne
2   middle, last, first     Superman, Kent, Clark
3   last, first, middle     Prince, Diana, Wonderwoman
```

INTO:

```
ID  ORDER                   NAME
1   first                   Bruce
1   middle                  Batman
1   last                    Wayne
2   middle                  Superman
2   last                    Kent
2   first                   Clark
3   last                    Prince
3   first                   Diana
3   middle                  Wonderwoman
```

Comment: Which version you have?

Comment: Why not make the effort to normalise your data, rather than making another form of denormalisation?

Comment: @larnu thinking wishfully, perhaps this question is because that normalisation is being undertaken ;)

Comment: Considering you could normalise the data in one go, I sitting on the side of "unlikely" for that one @CaiusJard :(

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not have very good string processing functions.  You can do this using a recursive CTE, though:

```
with cte as (
      select id,
             convert(varchar(max), left(ord, charindex(',', ord) - 1)) as ord,
             convert(varchar(max), left(name, charindex(',', name) - 1)) as name,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(ord, 1, charindex(',', ord) + 1, '')) as ord_rest,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(name, 1, charindex(',', name) + 1, '')) as name_rest,
             1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select id,
             convert(varchar(max), left(ord_rest, charindex(',', ord_rest + ',') - 1)) as ord,
             convert(varchar(max), left(name_rest, charindex(',', name_rest + ',') - 1)) as name,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(ord_rest, 1, charindex(',', ord_rest + ',') + 1, '')) as ord_rest,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(name_rest, 1, charindex(',', name_rest + ',') + 1, '')) as name_rest,
             lev + 1
      from cte
      where ord_rest <> '' and lev < 10
     )
select id, ord, name
from cte
order by id, lev
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0c4a2d2809b4d96502cf643e0f91b81a) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a parse/split function that returns the sequence, this becomes a small matter using a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Select A.ID 
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select [Order] = B1.RetVal
                      ,[Name]  = B2.RetVal
                 From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse]([ORDER],',') B1
                 Join  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse]([NAME] ,',') B2 on B1.RetSeq=B2.RetSeq
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Order   Name
1   first   Bruce
1   middle  Batman
1   last    Wayne
2   middle  Superman
2   last    Kent
2   first   Clark
3   last    Prince
3   first   Diana
3   middle  Wonderwoman
```

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
          ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.'))) as A(x)
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

Comment: Thank you! It has solved most of my problems and helped me figure out what I need to do next.

Comment: @TinaChan Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the other answers a bit hard to follow - they're neat tricks for sure but I think anyone coming to maintain them might be like "whaaaat?". Here I work out the indexes of the commas (the first comma string index goes in o1/n1, the second comma goes in o2/n2) in the first cte, cut the string up (substring between 1 and first comma, substring between first and second comma, substring after third comma) in the second cte and then use a couple of unions to turn the results from 7 columns into 3

```
WITH idxs AS
(
SELECT 
  id,
  order,
  name,
  CHARINDEX(',', [order]) as o1,
  CHARINDEX(',', [order], CHARINDEX(',', [order]) + 1) as o2,
  CHARINDEX(',', name) as n1,
  CHARINDEX(',', name, CHARINDEX(',', name) + 1) as n2
FROM
  t
),
cuts as (
SELECT
  id,
  SUBSTRING([order], 1, o1-1) as ord1,
  SUBSTRING([order], o1+1, o2-o1-1) as ord2,
  SUBSTRING([order], o2+1, 4000) as ord3,
  SUBSTRING(name, 1, n1-1) as nam1,
  SUBSTRING(name, n1+1, n2-n1-1) as nam2,
  SUBSTRING(name, n2+1, 4000) as nam3
FROM
  idxs
)

SELECT id, ord1 as [order], nam1 as name FROM cuts
UNION ALL
SELECT id, ord2, nam2 FROM cuts
UNION ALL
SELECT id, ord3, nam3 FROM cuts
```

Note that if your data sometimes has spaces in and sometimes does not you'll benefit from using either LTRIM/RTRIM in the output

if the spaces are always there after a comma, you could also adjust the substring indexes to cut the spaces out (any start index that is x+1 would be x+2 and the length would hence have to be -2)